# pd.DataFrame.to_sql() is prepending the server name and username to the table name

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have a Pandas dataframe `df` which I want to push to a relational database as a table. I setup a connection object (`<Connection>`) using SQLAlchemy (pyodbc is the connection engine), and called the command

`df.to_sql(<Table_Name>, <Connection>)`

which I was able to confirm was written as a table to the desired relational database by visual examination of it in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). But in the left-hand-side list of databases and their tables in SSMS I see that it has named it

`<Sender_Server>\<Username>.<Table_Name>`

where `<Sender_Server>` is (I think) related to the name of the server I ran the Python command from, `<Username>` is my username on that server, and `<Table_Name>` is the desired table name.

When I right-click on the table and select to query the top one thousand rows I get a query of the form

```sql
SELECT * FROM [<Data_Base_Name>].[<Sender_Server>\<Username>].[<Table_Name>]
```

which also has the `<Sender_Server>\<Username>` info in it. The inclusion of `<Sender_Server>\<Username>` is undesired behaviour in our use case.

How can I instead have the data pushed such that

```sql
SELECT * FROM [<Data_Base_Name>].[<Table_Name>]
```

is the appropriate query?

Comment: I think this undesired information is actually related to the schema, rather than the source server.

Comment: Yes, that is probably the default schema for the user that is connecting to the database. Try adding `schema="dbo"` to the `to_sql()` call.

Comment: @GordThompson Using `schema="dbo"` in the `to_sql()` was precisely what I ended up using. Please post this as an answer so I can reward you for offering this suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `.to_sql()` assumes the default schema for the current user unless `schema="schema_name"` is provided. Say, for example, the database contains a table named `dbo.thing` and the database user named `joan` has a default schema named `engineering`. If Joan does

```py
df.to_sql("thing", engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
```

it will not append to `dbo.thing` but will instead try to create an `engineering.thing` table and append to that. If Joan wants to append to `dbo.thing` she needs to do

```py
df.to_sql("thing", engine, schema="dbo", if_exists="append", index=False)
```